# Windows 2003 crashing with .NET 3.5 SP1

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, crash, windows-server-2003, crash-dumps

I have a product I developed based on Linq and Entity Framwork. 
Before they upgraded to SP1 I got an exeption when I tried to find the
Entity Framework DLL.

I asked the customer to upgrade to SP1. After that, they are getting bluescreen.

Are there any known problems with .NET 3.5 SP1 and Windows 2003?
I have a dump file. I downloaded the dbg-tools and I get

Bugcheck code 1000008E
Arguments c0000005 de228de9 f2ec35dc 00000000

But I could not find anything (except 1000008E, and obviusly c0000005 on the net)

What should I do? Should I file a issue report at Microsoft?

Comment: David, that is not a good advice. It makes more sense to analyze and understand the problem.

Comment: David, I have tried to build another box, at it works. 
But I cannot ask my customer to rebuild their production server for my small product, when they have weeks of work to rebuid it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a kernel mode exception happened, that was caused by an access violation. Generally this will create a dump file, that can be analyzed with the windbg debugger. Load the dump file in the debugger and get the native call stack and the clr call stack. This will help pointing out the problem.

Comment: I have done that, hence the bugcheck code in my comment. But i dont get much other information. Do I need to run the debugger on the same machine to get good information?